# Front wheels keep locking on 04 Honda Accord

Tags: honda, brakes, accord

I recently changed my front brakes & calipers ever since my front wheels keep locking up. The mechanic has replaced the calipers yet again & bled the entire system still the same problem. Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Both sides lock up at the same time? And by lock up, does this mean it  happens any time or does it happen when you step on the brake pedal or ... when/how?

Comment: It will allow me to drive it to a destination but then when it’s time to leave again the front wheels won’t turn! Once it does start going it’s like I’m forcing it to go then i smell the brakes burning so I pull over and stop only to see smoke coming from the front two tires

Comment: I drove it to the store about an hour ago but then I couldn’t leave because the car just wouldn’t move I can tell it’s trying but the wheels won’t move

Comment: Was this the same issue why you had the brakes changed in the first place? Or were they just worn out?

Comment: No they were just worn

Comment: If they were just worn out and working before you took it to the mechanic, then the mechanic needs to fix what they did wrong. If they were working before, they should be working now. Since they are not working now, the mechanic has screwed something up. Do not fear telling the mechanic they need to fix their work. They should have provided a working vehicle considering they received a working vehicle.

Comment: Sounds like the return hole in the master cylinder (allows fluid to pass between the master cylinder and the reservoir when the brake pedal is not pushed) is plugged. And Paulster2 is exactly right: take it back to the mechanic who did the work.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven’t been able to catch up with him again  I think I’m just going to get the brakes changed again and I’m also going to change the master cylinder hoping this fixes the issue